# mange former project in Altium

Tags: altium, bom

I have several projects that designed by a different designer .They used personal library with specific Item ID for the same component. I want to manage them and link them to a supplier. If I do that one by one, it takes a long time. Is there any way to change them or apply changes on all of them in short way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem but it has more to do with updating component links.

There isn't a good way outside of writing your own script and doing it that way. I haven't had the time to do that so I just update them manually.